# Custom 404 using Spring DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring, annotations, http-status-code-404, web.xml

I've set up web.xml as below.  I also have an annotation-based controller, which takes in any URL pattern and then goes to the corresponding jsp (I've set that up in the -servlet.xml).  However, If I go to a page that ends in .html (and whose jsp doesn't exist), I don't see the custom 404 page (and see the below error in the log).  Any page that doesn't end in .html, I can see the custom 404 page.

How can I configure to have a custom 404 page for any page that goes through the DispatcherServlet?

Also want to add that if I set my error page to a static page (ie. error.htm) it works, but if I change it to a jsp (ie. error.jsp), I get the IllegalStateException.  Any help would be appreciated.

**log error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:606)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:195)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:124)
```

**controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/**"})

public ModelAndView test() {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

    return modelAndView;
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>my_servlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

...

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>my_servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

...

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: Try this -> http://ekiras.blogspot.in/2015/02/custom-error-404-error-page-in-spring-mvc.html

Answer (score 34):

One option is to map all your error pages through your dispatcher servlet.

**Create a new HTTP error controller:**

```
@Controller
public class HTTPErrorController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/errors/404.html")
    public String handle404() {
        return "errorPageTemplate";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/errors/403.html")
    ...

}
```

**Map the error pages in web.xml**

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/errors/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: @Stefan Haberl, why change @Rob's post rather than just post your simplified version as a new answer?

Comment: Can anyone verify that this solution works?  It doesn't for me (Spring 3.0.5)

Comment: This code example is almost verbatim from some of our applications and works as expected. What problem are you having? I can help debug.

Comment: Isn't it missing something? Why would the request to go /error/404.html? I get how the controller would fetch such a request, just not why the request would go there.

Comment: @Andreas the request would go there because you are mapping it in web.xml at the servlet layer. The servlet will map your 404 to /errors/404.html and then the Spring Controller will be able to catch it up. The Controller knows nothing about it is a 404, only will get a matching request mapping, the servlet don't know it's pulling the error to Spring, just will redirect to a web address that happens to be mapped to a Spring controller.

Comment: I implemented this solution but it's resulting in errors in our log saying "No mapping found for URI..."

Comment: Yeah, I have not been able to get this to work. I am implementing this in Broadleaf, an ecom stack built ontop of Spring MVC. Will post if I ever find the answer!