# Spring MVC 3: How to provide dynamic content to error page for HTTP 404 errors?

Tags: spring-mvc, exception, http-status-code-404

**What I want:**

I want to provide a model to the HTTP 404 error page. Instead of writing a static error Page, which is specified within web.xml, I want to use an
exception controller, which handles HTTP 404 errors.

**What I did:**

Removed error page tag from web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/httpError.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

and implemented the following exception handler methods inside my AbstractController class:

```
@ExceptionHandler(NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException.class)
public ModelAndView handleNoSuchRequestException(NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException ex) {
    ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
        model.addAttribute("modelkey", "modelvalue");
        return new ModelAndView("/http404Error", model);
}

@ExceptionHandler(NullPointerException.class)
public ModelAndView handleAllExceptions(NullPointerException e) {
        ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
        model.addAttribute("modelkey", "modelvalue");
        return new ModelAndView("/exceptionError", model);
}
```

**What is does:**

It works find for exceptions, but not for HTTP error code status 404. It seems like HTTP 404 errors are handled by DispatcherServlet by default. Is it possible to change this behaviour?

And how can I catch 404 errors in my exception handler?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196569/custom-404-using-spring-dispatcherservlet

Comment: Thanks for the cross reference. It works as it is described in the other post. Instead of using the **@ExceptionHandler** annotation you have to use the **@RequestMapping** annotation, which makes sense.Cheers

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get some dynamic content in your 404 page or any other error page, map the page to a controller in your spring context.
For example, declare a controller named "404.htm" and try to request the page /404.htm to insure that it's working fine,
then in your web.xml write the following :

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.htm</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this url http://blog.codeleak.pl/2013/04/how-to-custom-error-pages-in-tomcat.html

Explains how to create a controller to get the error and put parameters to whow them in the .jsp.