# Using Spring MVC's @RequestMapping in order to map any URL not found by more specific @RequestMappings

Tags: spring-mvc

I would like to use **Spring MVC**'s `@RequestMapping` annotation in order to map any URLs not found by more specific `@RequestMapping`s.

*Let me illustrate with an example*:

Say a URL such as "`/ICannotBeFound.htm`" is not mapped by the application other's and higher-priority `@RequestMapping`s. How can I map it to a low prioriry `@RequestMapping`?

Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1252763/106261

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handle error 404 with Spring controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356549/handle-error-404-with-spring-controller)

Comment: Thanks NimChimpsky: That provides a solution!!